# In SXA, rendering variant - need to generate context item url

Tags: sxa

I have a list of item and by using reference variant, I'm able to loop the items with the multi-list values. Now each tile which is displayed should wrap with two fields (ie., image and title) with anchor tag that points to context item on clicking this should open a details page of that tile.

[image]

Now that problem is after check the "islink" with the wrapping of anchor (`<a>`) between two fields and the link which is generating the relative URL is from (site tenant/Site/Home) instead of excluding till start item path as shown below:

**Actual URL:** http://domainname/sitetenant/sitename/home/Company/..../..../..../itemname

**Expected URL:**http://domainname/Company/about/..../..../itemname

Please suggest a way to generate a context item URL excluding start item path.

Using SXA 1.8 on 9.0.2 sitecore.

Comment: Take a look here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15884/general-link-value-in-rendering-variants

Comment: Thanks for the link, but in that existing this little different than mine, they are reading link list but in my case, I want the context item as a link.

Comment: Maybe you should go with custom Variant Token which will simply generate a proper link for you? Take a look: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-a-custom-token-for-a-rendering-variant.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can go for Scriban template to create your rendering variant, sometihng like below code would help to achieve this:

```
    <div class="Title">
     <a href="{{i_item.url}}"> 
        {{ i_item.Title }} 
        {{ i_item.Image }}
      </a>
    </div>
```

This is just a reference code and I have not tested. Please let me know if you need more info.

Hope this helps someone!!!